# Python/Psychopy: Instantiating multiple circle objects from a class

Tags: python, class, psychopy

I've made a class that contains a circle (a Psychopy Circle object). I want to know how I can instantiate 2 circle objects using this class, each for example, with a different fill color.

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.circle = visual.Circle(win, units = 'deg', pos=(1,1), 
        radius=1, lineColor="black", fillColor="red")

        self.components = [self.circle]

    def draw(self):
        [component.draw() for component in self.components]

circle=Circle() #red colour
circle2=Circle() #blue colour if possible
```

Is there a way for me to instantiate circle2 whilst accessing some of the visual.circle parameters e.g. to change it's position or fill color? This is my first use of classes. Currently, If I draw 'circle' and 'cirle2' to the screen, one simply overlays the other, as one is merely a copy of the other.

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Typically, you would subclass `psychopy.visual.Circle` to inherit all functionality. I don't understand the bit with the list, since you only instantiate a single `psychopy.visual.Circle` inside your class anyway. I assume you simply want to use a list of `psychopy.visual.Circle` objects?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a list of psychopy.visual.Circle objects, but have them be different colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification in the comment, I assume you want something like this:

```
class Circle(psychopy.visual.circle.Circle):
    def __init__(self, win, lineColor='black', fillColor='red'):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(
            win=win, lineColor=lineColor, fillColor=fillColor, units='deg',
            pos=(1,1), radius=1)
```

`Circle` would then default to `units='deg'`, `pos=(1,1)`, and `radius=1`. You could, however, specify different `lineColor`s and `fillColor`s for each instance. Since `Circle` inherits from the PsychoPy `visual.Circle` class, it has all its features. The call to `super()` actually initializes the parent class. See e.g. [this post](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/super/working-python-super-function) for more information on the `super()` function.

Let's put this to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from psychopy import core, visual, monitors
import psychopy.visual.circle


class Circle(psychopy.visual.circle.Circle):
    def __init__(self, win, lineColor='black', fillColor='red'):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(
            win=win, lineColor=lineColor, fillColor=fillColor, units='deg',
            pos=(1,1), radius=1)


def main():
    # Create a temporary monitor configuration.
    monitor = monitors.Monitor('test_display')
    monitor.setWidth(60)
    monitor.setDistance(80)
    monitor.setSizePix((1440, 900))

    win = visual.Window(monitor=monitor)

    colors = ('red', 'green', 'blue')
    circles = [Circle(win=win, fillColor=color) for color in colors]

    for circle in circles:
        circle.draw()
        win.flip()
        core.wait(1)

    core.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code will create three `Circle`s with different colors, and display them one after the other. I had to create a temporary monitor configuration or else PsychoPy would refuse to open a `Window` on my current computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the constructor of the class (the `__init__` method) adding an atribute `color` and in the `fillColor` change the value to the variable `color`. With the position you can do the same.

Comment: What does that look like? I've tried 'self.color = color' underneath 'self.circle..' but I get 'global name 'color' is not defined'

Comment: The code looks like : class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, color, posx, posy):
        self.circle = visual.Circle(win, units = 'deg', pos=(posx,posy), 
        radius=1, lineColor="black", fillColor=color)

        self.components = [self.circle]

    def draw(self):
        [component.draw() for component in self.components]

circle=Circle('red', 1, 1) #red colour at positon (1, 1)
circle2=Circle('blue', 2, 1) #blue colour at position (2, 1)